# Implications of weak convergence in Lp e change of measure spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

In the paper "A uniform algebra of analytic functions" of Carne-Cole-and-Gamelin. The Theorem 6.4 says:

Theorem 6.4: Let $\mu$ be a positive measure on some measure space, let $2\leq p<\infty$, and let $N$ be a integer satisfying $N\geq p$. Let $\{f_j\}$ be a sequence in $L_p(\mu)$ such that $f_j\longrightarrow 0$ weakly, and $F(f_j)\longrightarrow 0$ for every $F\in\mathcal{P}_N(L_p(\mu))$. Then $\|f_j\|_p\longrightarrow 0$.

Here, $\mathcal{P}_N(L_p(\mu))$ is the space of N-homogeneous polynomials.

Proof: Since the $f_j$'s are all carried by some $\sigma$-finite set, we can assume that the measure $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite. Replacing $\mu$ by a mutually absolutely continuous measure, we can assume that $\mu$ is a probability measure. $\cdots$

My questions. Someone can help me understand this change of a arbitrary measure space to a probability measure space? Why the functions are carried by a $\sigma$-finite set?

Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_{j,n} = \{ |f_j| > 1/n\}$.  Since $f_j \in L^p$, each $A_{j,n}$ must have finite measure.  So if we let $A = \bigcup_{j,n} A_{j,n}$, then $A$ is $\sigma$-finite.  And every $f_j$ vanishes outside $A$.  This is what they mean by "all $f_j$'s are carried by some $\sigma$-finite set."

I'll leave the part about changing to a probability measure for someone else.

Comment: Thanks. Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space with $\mu$ $\sigma$-finite. If $X=\cup_{n+1}^\infty E_n$, disjoint  union, where $\mu(E_n)<\infty$, so the measure $\lambda(B):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(B\cap E_n)}{2^n\mu(E_n)}$ is a probability measure mutually absolutely continuous to $\mu$. If the Theorem holds to measure $\lambda$ it holds to $\mu$? Arguments of this kind are used for example in the Radon-Nikodym Theorem, but I don't know if it fits this situation.

Comment: @L26: No, that part is not obvious to me.  In particular, convergence in $L^p(\lambda)$ certainly need not imply convergence in $L^p(\mu)$

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found the answear. If $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite measure so define $\lambda$ by $d\lambda=gd\mu$, where $g$ is positive $\mu$-a.e and $\int gd\mu=1$. Then $\lambda$ is a probability measure, and $L_p(\mu)$ is isometric to $L_p(\lambda)$. I found this in the book Banach Space Theory: The Basis for Linear and Nonlinear Analysis - Marián Fabian, et al.